# Postgres SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table like follows:

```
Meter Serial    Date       |  Reading
    A          2017-01-01      10
    B          2017-02-10      20
    A          2017-03-05      20
    B          2017-05-01      100
    A          2017-06-01      300
```

Is it possible to get a query that displays like follows:

```
Meter   |    Date Start  |  Start Reading  |  Date End  |  End Reading
 A           2017-01-01          10          2017-03-05      20
 B           2017-02-10          20          2017-05-01      30
 A           2017-03-05          20          2017-06-01      300
```

Note:  The readings do not come daily.  But they are unique for a given day (e.g. you cannot have two readings on the same day)

This is the current query I am working with:

```
with tbl as (select row_number() over(order by read_date) as rn, meter_serial, meter_channel, total_meter_read, read_date
from meter_reading_total)
select l.meter_serial, l.read_date, l.total_meter_read, r.read_date, r.total_meter_read
from tbl as l
left outer join
tbl as r
on r.rn = l.rn + 1
and r.meter_serial = l.meter_serial
and r.meter_channel = l.meter_channel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window functions FTW

```
SELECT
  meter_serial,
  meter_date                     AS start_date,
  readings                       AS start_reads,
  lead(meter_date) OVER read_wdw AS end_date,
  lead(readings)   OVER read_wdw AS end_reads
FROM read_meter
WINDOW read_wdw AS (
  PARTITION BY meter_serial
  ORDER BY     meter_date ASC
)
ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/79a94/9) for this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.date as startdate, l.reading as startreading, r.date as 
enddate, r.endreading from
sample as l
left outer join
sample as r
on r.date = l.date + interval '1' day;
```

Self join by 1 day interval if you want it by dates. Else if you want by the  record order change join condition to **r.id = l.id + 1**

If your table has no id column, you can use the rownumber function and cte
as

```
with tbl as (select row_number() over(order by dt) as rn, rd, dt
from sample)
select l.dt, l.rd, r.dt, r.rd
from tbl as l
left outer join
tbl as r
on r.rn = l.rn + 1;
```

Changing `order by dt` to `order by 1` will join the table at the date ranges even if they are not sorted.

Comment: The table does not have equal date ranges.  Have a look at the fourth reading.

Comment: I think the problem I am facing is that I have multiple meters in the same table and I need to sort by meter.  At the bottom of my question I will post my actual query I am running

Comment: Change `row_number() over(order by read_date)` to `row_number() over(partition by meter_serial order by read_date)` in your query

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
SELECT sub1.meter, sub1.date as date_start, sub1.reading as start_reading, sub2.meter, sub2.date as date_end, sub2.reading as end_reading
FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY meter, date ASC) AS row, t.*
FROM t) sub1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY meter, date ASC) AS row, t.*
FROM t) sub2 ON sub1.row = sub2.row -1
AND sub1.meter = sub2.meter
```

Try it here: http://rextester.com/XZDOX35079

Comment: same result.  I am only getting results where the days are only 1 day apart, but I need a range.

Comment: I think its because I have more information that I need.  e.g. different meters in the same table.  have updated the question...